# How to do Maximum Intensity Projection [ MIP ] in WebGL

Tags: webgl, three.js

I have created a demo [ http://jsfiddle.net/georgeneil/cfrsj/16/ ] using three.js which performs blending, ie THREE.AdditiveBlending. But this is giving me a white light effect and hence a feeling of loss of information.

What i need a blended result which can project the Maximum Intensity. How can i do this using three.js ?

In OpenGL i was able to do this using glBlendEquationEXT(GL_MAX_EXT).

I have updated the demo [ http://jsfiddle.net/georgeneil/cfrsj/21 ], to make the concept more clear. Now there are 8 particles, 4 are RED color and remaining 4 are black color. If MIP works properly we could see only the RED particles even when BLACK overlaps RED [image]

What i am looking for can be explained from this demo [ http://jsfiddle.net/georgeneil/cfrsj/28/ ]. I need to see black pixels where ever its NOT overlaping with the Red pixel. I need to get effects as shown in the attached image.[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question then this should be a correct solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/cfrsj/26/

Edit:

This is how I simulated the function. I use NormalBlending.

first I make sure that the colors saturate with

```
    float r= vColor.r > 0.0? 1.0 : 0.0;
    float g= vColor.g > 0.0? 1.0 : 0.0; 
    float b= vColor.b > 0.0? 1.0 : 0.0;
```

then I check if alpha is nessecary with

```
    gl_FragColor.a = gl_FragColor.a * 
                     texture2D( texture, gl_PointCoord ).r * 
                     (test.r > 0.0 ? 1.0 : 
                         (test.g > 0.0?1.0:
                         (test.b > 0.0?1.0:0.0)));
```

Comment: Here we could see only the brightest pixel. What i am looking for can be explained from this demo [ http://jsfiddle.net/georgeneil/cfrsj/28/ ]. I need to see black pixels where ever its NOT overlaping with the Red pixel. I need to get effects as shown in the attached image.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug in webgl. A workaround is to initialize gl with

```
gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl", { alpha: false } );
```

Comment: I didn't get what you mean. Can you make it work in the jsfiddle demo.

Comment: I think the MIP logic is still not working. I have updated the demo [ http://jsfiddle.net/georgeneil/cfrsj/21/ ], to make the concept more clear. Now there are 8 particles, 4 are RED color and remaining 4 are black color. If MIP works properly we could see only the RED particles even when BLACK overlaps RED

Comment: It's a bit hard to get what you're trying to achive. You say you want transparency but you set the alpha value of your particles to 1.

Comment: But its possible in OpenGL via  glBlendEquationEXT(GL_MAX_EXT). [ http://leri.univ-reims.fr/~bittar/cours/OpenGL/opengl/glBlendEquationEXT.html ]

Answer (score 0):

You could be interested in the two following links:

- https://www.khronos.org/webgl/public-mailing-list/archives/1212/msg00066.html
- http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/proposals/EXT_blend_minmax/